# How to get a public OpenPGP key only knowing its fingerprint?

Tags: cryptography, gnupg, public-key, openpgp

I have only an OpenPGP key's public fingerprint. I do not know the key ID or almost anything else.

How can I get the corresponding public key? Are there any online service to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## How the Fingerprint and Long and Short Key IDs are Related

Each OpenPGP key has a fingerprint attached, calculated mainly from its public key packet which also contains the creation time. The calculation is defined in [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 12.2. Key IDs and Fingerprints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-12.2).

There are short and long key IDs, which resemble the lower 32 respective 64 bits of the fingerprint. For example, looking at the IDs of my OpenPGP key:

```
fingerprint: 0D69 E11F 12BD BA07 7B37  26AB 4E1F 799A A4FF 2279
long id:                                    4E1F 799A A4FF 2279
short id:                                             A4FF 2279
```

Fingerprints and key IDs are used, as sharing and comparing a whole key with usually 1024 to 8096 bits (adding some more for headers like the creation date) is *very* impractical.

### Receiving Keys from Key Servers

There is a bunch of key servers used to distribute keys -- they communicate with each other, choose any of them. GnuPG's option `--keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net` (often set in it's configuration file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` for Linux/UNIX systems, another path on Windows) uses a pool that will chose a random one each time you use it.

You can use any of those short and long IDs respective the full fingerprint to fetch the key using the `--recv-keys` command in GnuPG, while the fingerprint is the most specific (and [chances for collisions with short key IDs are highest](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74009/19837)).

If no colliding keys exist, following statements would fetch the same key:

```
gpg --recv-keys 0D69E11F12BDBA077B3726AB4E1F799AA4FF2279
gpg --recv-keys 4E1F799AA4FF2279
gpg --recv-keys A4FF2279
```

If you want to query the key servers from your browser, make sure to search for the fingerprint, long or short key ID prefixed by `0x` to indicate a search for key IDs (the GnuPG command line interface will do this for you automatically).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are [servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_%28cryptographic%29#Keyserver_examples) for this. You can get key like this:

```
gpg --recv-keys <KEY_ID>
```

**Update**: [see](https://futureboy.us/pgp.html) how KEY_ID interconnected with fingerprint:

```
Fingerprint:    EC2392F2EDE74488680DA3CF5F2B4756ED873D23
Long Key ID:                            5F2B4756ED873D23
Short Key ID:                                   ED873D23
```

Comment: No. I not have <KEY_ID>. I have ONLY fingerprint (=hash(public_key)).